# Isomorphism of power series

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $Q$ be a prime ideal of $R$. Show that  $R ([[x]])/(Q[[x]])$ is isomorphic to $R/Q [[x]].$

Comment: I want to know if I can Suppose the function like this: φ:R[[x]]⟶R⁄Q[[x]].

Answer (score 3):

Compute the kernel of the surjective homomorphism $$\varphi:R[[x]]\to (R/Q)[[x]]$$ that sends $a_i x^i\longmapsto (a_i+Q)x^i$ for all $i.$ Then invoke the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: Ragib, do you think you should have $x^i$ instead of $x_i$ in your answer above?

Comment: @AmiteshDatta Yes of course! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No problem, Ragib!

Answer (score 1):

Ragib's answer above is excellent and sufficient. If you're interested in an alternative (perhaps less concrete) manner of viewing this problem, then I think the answer below provides this.

The short exact sequence:

(1) $0\to Q\to R\to R/Q\to 0$

results in the short exact sequence:

(2) $0\to Q[[x]]\to R[[x]]\to R/Q[[x]]\to 0$

if we apply the "power series functor" $F:\bf{Rngs}\to \bf{Rngs}$. (The category $\bf{Rngs}$ is that consisting of rings without unity so an ideal in a ring corresponds to a subobject of an object in this category.) Of course, a short exact sequence such as (2) is equivalent to an isomorphism $(R/Q)[[x]]\cong R[[x]]/Q[[x]]$ (and this would be true in any abelian category).

I hope this helps!

**Addendum**: Explictly, the functor $F$ is given by the rule $F(A)=A[[x]]$, the power series rng (no typo here!) of an object $A\in \bf{Rngs}$. If $\phi:A\to B$ is a morphism in $\bf{Rngs}$, then $F(\phi):F(A)\to F(B)$, i.e., $F(\phi):A[[x]]\to B[[x]]$ is defined by the rule:

$F(\phi)(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_ix^i)$

$=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \phi(a_i)x^i\in F(B)$

for all $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_ix^i\in F(A)$.

Comment: I don't understand this "answer": you simply rephrased the problem in terms of Category Theory.

Comment: @YACP You're right but I think that my answer furnishes a nice alternative way of looking at the problem. In saying that, proving (2) is exact is straightforward, I think. (Though whether it's easier than answering the actual question from the OP's perspective is a different matter!)

Comment: @YACP If you downvoted (and I apologise if you didn't!), then could you please let me know how I could improve my answer? It's intended to complement Ragib's answer for someone who is familiar with category theory and I do think it answers this question if you can prove that (2) is exact ...